# Crystal Server doesn't seem to pass credential to SharePoint WebDAV folder?

Tags: sharepoint, crystal-reports-server

We have Crystal Server setup to automatically deposit generated reports to a SharePoint WebDAV folder. The Crystal Server user is setup in sharepoint with the right permissions but yet, authentication fails when it tries to access the folder. We are using NTLM.

Any idea what could be causing this? Should we use Kerberos? Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Report Server is Java-based (Tomcat or WAC) and Java SSO does not support NTLM so yes, you will need to use Kerberos.  I just walked through configuring SSO for our Crystal Report Server environment and had to go down the Kerberos route.